# Expanding in powers of $\epsilon$ and big O notation

Tags: calculus, power-series, calculus-of-variations, linear-approximation

I do not understand how to approach (D.1) equation
[image]


Where did that big O notation come from?Is it using taylor series and linear approximation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: They are expanding in powers of $\epsilon.$

Comment: @Nameless It's said in the text, but what does that mean?

Comment: Think of $\epsilon$ as the variable.

Comment: @Nameless Could you please write a full response to the question? I absolutely appreciate it.

Comment: Any comment on this question?!

Comment: You have essentially $f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + O(h^2)$, does this look more familiar?

Comment: @Nameless No, it's not familiar for me, what's familiar for me is, $L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac {f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+ ...$ which is the Taylor approximation of the function centered at $x=a$

Comment: Substitute $\epsilon = x -a.$